# Actionbar menu not working for firstclick

Tags: android

This is my code.action bar click function formsubmit() not working for first time.second time working perfectly.but intent working perfectly everytime
 help me!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.contactform);
   name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_name);
   phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_phone);
   email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_email);
   address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_address);
        //submit.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
   submit=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.action_submit);
   submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
        public void onClick(View V)
        {
           formsubmit();
        }
   });

}


@Override
public boolean  onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the me this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.form_submit, menu);

    return true;
    }


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_submit) {

        formsubmit();
        Intent i=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);


        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void formsubmit()
{   
   String getName=name.getText().toString();
   String getPhone=phone.getText().toString();
   String getEmail=email.getText().toString();
   String getAddress=address.getText().toString();
   handler=new datahandler(getBaseContext());
   handler.open();
   long id=handler.insertdata(getName,getPhone,getEmail,getAddress);
 }
```

}

```
05-26 14:18:07.667: D/AndroidRuntime(939): Shutting down VM
05-26 14:18:07.667: W/dalvikvm(939): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.addressbook/com.example.addressbook.customnameadd}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at com.example.addressbook.customnameadd.onCreate(customnameadd.java:50)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-26 14:18:07.697: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  ... 11 more
05-26 14:23:07.787: I/Process(939): Sending signal. PID: 939 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move below code to your oncreate function

```
submit=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.action_submit);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
     public void onClick(View V)
     {
        formsubmit();
     }
});
```

and change function

```
private void formsubmit()
{   
   String getName=name.getText().toString();
   String getPhone=phone.getText().toString();
   String getEmail=email.getText().toString();
   String getAddress=address.getText().toString();
   handler=new datahandler(getBaseContext());
   handler.open();
   long id=handler.insertdata(getName,getPhone,getEmail,getAddress);
 }
```

and remove below line from public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

```
submit=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.action_submit);
```

Comment: i moved the code to oncreate().when run the application it showing unfortunately application has stopped.

Comment: can you post your oncreate function and logcat

Comment: my friend your code does not reflect what I suggested you in my answer

Comment: are you sure R.id.action_submit is a textview or button, your casting it as textview

Comment: updated. R.id.action_submit is a textview...sorry bro i am new to android

Comment: which one is line 50?